# Using a class as a decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, python-3.6, python-decorators

This is my first time trying this, so...

I am following:  https://www.python-course.eu/python3_decorators.php

The goal is that when I initialize an instance of Foo like this:

```
f = Foo(10, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

The output from print(f) needs to look like this:

```
Instance of Foo, vars = {'x': 10, 'y': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
```

The decorator class is to function as a kind of automatic **repr**.

I have this:

```
class ClassDecorator(object):
    def __init__(self, cls):
        self.cls = cls
        print("An instance of Foo was initialized")

    def __call__(self, cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Instance of Foo, vars = ", kwargs)

@ClassDecorator
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

f = Foo(10, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
print(f)
```

Which yields:

```
An instance of Foo was initialized
Instance of Foo, vars =  {}
None
```

I don't think I want *args, but without it my program errors out with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
An instance of Foo was initialized
  File "C:/Users/Mark/PycharmProjects/main/main.py", line 17, in <module>
    f = Foo(10, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
TypeError: __call__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

I understand the missing argument issue, but if 10 is to be 'x' and [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] is to be 'y', then I am just not understanding why **kwargs is insufficient.

Comment: Your class ins't overriding `__repr__`, it's interfering with the initialisation of `Foo`. Where you print *"An instance of Foo was initialized"* is actually where an instance of `ClassDecorator` is initialized, `Foo` is never getting initialized. You don't get a `cls` argument to `ClassDecorator.__call__`, it just gets `*args` and `**kwargs`.

Comment: Why does any of this make you want to use a class as a decorator?

Comment: A questionable use-case for a decorator.

Comment: What is your question here? Are you asking why `**kwargs` without `*args` isn’t sufficient for forwarding? If so, all the stuff about class decorators and `__repr__` is irrelevant. Or is your question about how to write a class decorator that adds a method to its argument? Or something else?

Comment: If the question is about forwarding: `**kwargs` only collects unmatched keyword arguments, not unmatched positional arguments. And there’s no way it could do otherwise—there’s nothing in your `def` signature (or anywhere else) that could give Python any idea of what you were hoping for.

Comment: @abarnert  My question is ultimately how to write a class as a decorator.  What I posted is just the specifics of what I am supposed to accomplish.

Comment: @user2357112  it is for an assignment.

Comment: OK, you need to make it clearer what your decorator is supposed to accomplish. Is it supposed to just return the decorated class, but patches with a new `__repr__`? Return a wrapper class that delegates everything except `__repr__`? Return a class that, when called, actually returns an instance of the decorated class instead of an instance of itself, but prints out some custom message? …?

Comment: @jonrsharpe  I am not trying to override __repr__, just implement a decorator class that does basically the same thing just to learn the mechanics of class decorators.

Comment: Trying to learn about classes as decorators by doing this with one seems like trying to learn about hammers by peeling a banana with one.

Comment: @abarnert, As stated in my original post, the decorator is supposed to allow me to do a print(f) and produce the output specified above.

Comment: @MarkS The only way to affect what `print(f)` prints is to make sure the type of `f` has a `__str__` that does what you want (or, if it doesn’t have a `__str__`, a `__repr__` that does what you want). Printing out stuff at class creation and instance creation time won’t do that, you _do_ need to override/replace/patch/whatever the method. Conversely, if you don’t want to do that, then you can’t get the behavior you’re asking for.

Comment: Also, your existing decorator returns nothing from its `__call__`. This means you _can’t_ create an instance of `Foo`. If you try, you just get back `None`. Which is exactly what you’re seeing: `print(f)` prints out `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing a few different fundamental concepts here.

---

First, when you `print` an object, like `print(f)`, what that does is call the `__str__` method on the type of `f`. If nobody has defined `__str__`, the default `object.__str__` gets called, which just returns `f.__repr__`.

So, if you want to change what happens when you do a `print(f)`, you *have to* give `f`'s type a `__str__` (or `__repr__`) method that does what you want. Nothing you do anywhere else is going to have any effect.

---

Your decorator's `__init__` doesn't get called when an instance of `Foo` is initialized; it gets called when the *class* gets initialized. (Or, rather, when the decorator gets called on the class, right after class creation) It's the `__call__` that happens when you use that to create an instance.

Also, that `__call__` isn't going to get an extra `cls` parameter from anywhere, it's just going to get `self`, like any other normal method. That's why we had to store the decorated class as `self.cls` in the first place.

---

The point of a decorator is to return an object that can be used like the decorated object. Your `ClassDecorator` can be called like a class—but it returns nothing when you do so, instead of returning an instance. That means it's impossible to create instances; if you try, you just get `None`. Which is why `print(f)` prints `None`.

---

Finally, forwarding arguments usually requires both `*args` and `**kwargs`. `*args` collects any unexpected positional arguments into a tuple, and `**kwargs` collects any unexpected keyword arguments into a dict. When someone calls `Foo(10, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])`, there are two positional arguments and no keyword arguments. So `args` will be `(10, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])`, and `kwargs` will be `{}`. If you didn't have a `*args`, then you'd get a `TypeError`, because you don't have any explicit positional-or-keyword parameters to match those positional arguments with.

---

So, here's an example that fixes all of that. I'll do it by modifying the decorated class, but remember that this isn't the only way to do it, and there are pros and cons of each approach.

First, I'll show how to write a decorator that only does what you want for classes whose instance variables are `x` and `y`.

```
class ClassDecorator(object):
    def __init__(self, cls):
        def _str(self):
            typ = type(self).__name__
            vars = {'x': self.x, 'y': self.y}
            return(f"Instance of {typ}, vars = {vars}")
        cls.__str__ = _str
        self.cls = cls
        print(f"The class {cls.__name__} was created")

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f"An instance of {self.cls.__name__} was created with args {args} and kwargs {kwargs}")
        return self.cls(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now, when you use it, it does what you wanted:

```
>>> @ClassDecorator
... class Foo(object):
...     def __init__(self, x, y):
...         self.x = x
...         self.y = y
The class Foo was created
>>> f = Foo(10, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
An instance of Foo was created with args (10, 20) and kwargs {}
>>> print(f)
Instance of Foo, vars = {'x': 10, 'y': 20}
>>> f
<__main__.Foo at 0x127ecdcf8>
```

Of course if you want to override that last thing, you want to define `__repr__` the same way as `__str__`.

---

So, what if we want to use this on *any* class, without knowing in advance what its attributes will be? We could use the `inspect` module to find the attributes:

```
def _str(self):
    typ = type(self).__name__
    vars = {name: value for name, value in inspect.getmembers(self) if not name.startswith('_')}
    return(f"Instance of {typ}, vars = {vars}")
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I appreciate it.